# k8s-device-plugin: How to set deviceIDStrategy value with docker

Tags: kubernetes, nvidia

I use k8s-device-plugin [https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin]running locally with docker:

```
docker run \
-it \
--security-opt=no-new-privileges \
--cap-drop=ALL \
--network=none \
-v /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins:/var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins \
nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:devel
```

Deployment via helm has customizable value `deviceIDStrategy` ，I want to set `deviceIDStrategy=index` with docker.

I have try `docker run -e deviceIDStrategy=index` but it is not work.

So how to set `deviceIDStrategy=index` with docker.

Thanks.

Comment: deviceIDStrategy=uuid is set by default as per https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#deployment-via-helm.

Comment: How about building the image with Option 3 from https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#build and changing the deviceIDStrategy in the code?